How to create a simple “Hello World” Action on Google Assistant in 2024?
I’ve already created a Skill for Alexa and now I’m starting my studies in developing Actions for Google Assistant. However, I’m having trouble creating a simple Action. Even after following the video “Google Assistant using Actions Builder” (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzptQqUIuSQ) and several other tutorials, I’m not succeeding. When I access the Actions Console, only the options: Invocation, Actions, and Account linking appear. When creating an Action, only Smart home is displayed, and in the tutorials I found, there are others. Since Dialogflow will no longer be used, I think I should do everything through the Actions Console of Actions Builder. And I found out that Google Assistant’s conversation actions will be deactivated on June 13, 2023. In short, how do I make a “hello world” of an Action on Google Assistant?
I appreciate any help in advance.
I’ve tried conducting various searches on the Internet, even using AI to assist me, and I’ve read Google’s documentation, but to no avail

Google removed this functionality some time ago. You can no longer build custom conversational actions (equivalent of custom Alexa skills).
Google actions sunset announcement

Dave Curley, I appreciate your response.
If necessary, I can create a simple Action. In other words, I’m not finding functionality in the Actions Builder.
The big question is: how do I make a “hello world” of an Action on Actions Builder?
